# $a_{n+1}=a_n+\cos a_n$ for all $n \in N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Define the sequence $a_n$ recursively by

$a_{n+1}=a_n+\cos a_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ with $a_1=1$

I've just begun with introduction to analysis and have witnessed these two sequences from the text. However, from the knowledge I've learned so far, I don't know how to prove that these sequeces converge and to what values they converge. How can I prove the convergence of these sequences?

Answer (score 5):

Taking $f(x) = x + \cos(x)$, we've defined
$$
a_{n+1} = f(a_{n})
$$
Note that $f'(x) = 1 - \sin(x)$, so that $|f'(x)| \leq 1/2$ for $x \in (\pi/6,5\pi/6)$, which contains $a_0 = 1$.  Moreover, $f(x) \in (\pi/6,5\pi/6)$ for every $x \in (\pi/6,5\pi/6)$.

This means that $f$ defines a contractive mapping on $(\pi/6,5\pi/6)$; that is, $|f(x)- f(y)| \leq \frac 12 |x-y|$.  Conclude that the sequence as defined must converge to a fixed point of $f$; that is, $a_n \to a$, and $a$ is the unique element of $(\pi/6,5\pi/6)$ satisfying $f(a) = a$.

See the Banach [fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).